# Best approach for comparing message in event with pre-defined strings

Tags: siddhi

I have some predefined string which number around 100. I have an input stream where i am receiving events and want to check whether the message in the event contain any of the predefined strings as their substring. I am using SiddhiQL. What is the best approach to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have around a hundred, it is better to store it in a database and load it to an in-memory table at startup using triggers

OR

You can use [siddhi-execution-list](https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-execution-list/api/1.0.0/#create-function) to create list object using queries. However, in this case the strings will be added in the siddhi app, so, any changes needs a siddhi app change.

Comment: Got it. But once loaded into an in-memory table, how can i check whether incoming events contain strings present in table as their substring?

Comment: You have to join the table, with 'on condition' as str:contains() https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-execution-string/api/5.0.9/#contains-function